# Boolean expression: What's the inverse of a 'let myString = aPossibleString'?

Tags: swift, boolean-expression

I'm trying to do the equivalent in Objective-C:

```
if (causeStr != nil) {
...
}
```

I would get a compiler error if do this:

```
if !(let myString = causeStr) {
}
```

So I'm left with this:

```
    if let myString = causeStr {
    } else {
        // ... do something
    }
```

Is there a *more-elegant* way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's a more elegant way, and coincidentally it's the same as in obj-c:

```
if myString == nil {
    ...
}
```

Note: Your 1st snippet of code should be:

```
if (causeStr == nil) {
    ...
}
```

otherwise it means I misunderstood your question...